# Setting a variable after a successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In java you can reference an outer class by stating its name followed by this.

```
class A {
    void A() {

    }
    class B {
        void B() {
            A.this.A();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am attempting to do something similar in javascript. Bellow I have constructor that makes an ajax call. This ajax call if successful sets the get method and the assets of the AssetManager.

```
function AssetManager(path) {

    this.assets = {};

    this.get = function(tag,name) {
        return 0;
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(o) {
            if (o.sprite) {
                var keys = Object.keys(o.sprite);
                for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    var obj1 = keys[i];
                    AssetManager.this.assets.sprite[obj1] = new Image();
                    AssetManager.this.assets.sprite[obj1].src = o.sprite[obj1];
                }
            }
            AssetManager.this.get = function (tag, name) {
                return assets[tag][name];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why did you put ajax call inside the class definition?

Comment: `AssetManager.this` ? Didn't it highlight anything in console ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 So that it can be ran with the object is initalized

Comment: What is `obj1` ? `this.assets.sprite` is not defined ? Appear to be overwriting same property at next line at `AssetManager.this.assets.sprite[obj1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to create variable and point it to this** prior executing ajax and access it within success handler:

```
function AssetManager(path) {
  // ......
  // Set this object to me variable
  var me = this;

  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(o) {
        if (o.sprite) {
            var keys = Object.keys(o.sprite);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var obj1 = keys[i];
                me.assets.sprite[obj1] = new Image();
                me.assets.sprite[obj1].src = o.sprite[obj1];
            }
        }
        me.get = function (tag, name) {
            return assets[tag][name];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that your ajax call is suppose to lazyly initialize other properties of your AssetManager, you need to save the reference of `this` so that it can be used inside ajax method (where the meaning of `this` will change)

```
function AssetManager(path) {

    this.assets = {};

    this.get = function(tag,name) {
        return 0;
    };

    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(o) {
            if (o.sprite) {
                var keys = Object.keys(o.sprite);
                for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    var obj1 = keys[i];
                    self.assets.sprite[obj1] = new Image();
                    self.assets.sprite[obj1].src = o.sprite[obj1];
                }
            }
            self.get = function (tag, name) {
                return assets[tag][name];
            }
        }
    });
}
```